# The wrong window opens when the program starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a pyqt program to register and authorize a user. I want to have a start window with buttons that, when clicked, will open either an authorization window or a registration window. But when I import the registration module, for example, the registration window opens instead of the main window. Can you please tell me where I made a mistake?

Main module:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from start import Ui_Form #py file with start window ui properties 
import registration #registration module
class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.RegButton.clicked.connect(reg_clicked())
        self.openreg=registration.mywindow(self)
        #self.ui.AuthButton.clicked.connect()

    def reg_clicked(self):
        self.openreg.show()
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = StartWindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Part of registration module:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import record_proc
from reg import Ui_Reg

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    number_of_samples=1
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Reg()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.RecordButton.clicked.connect(self.Recording)
        self.ui.AuthButton.clicked.connect(self.Register)
        self.ui.CheckLogin.clicked.connect(self.CheckLogin)
app2 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application2 = mywindow()
application2.show()
sys.exit(app2.exec())
```

Comment: remove the last four lines from `registration.py` or put them in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. If you import a module, all of the corresponding .py file is read and executed. In this case, when you import `registration`, the last four lines in your `registration.py` file will create a `QApplication` instance, create and show a registration window and start the event loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you mix executable code and library code.

When you do `import registration`
in your main module, that will execute the `registration.py` file.
That means it will run every line of code in that file, including the `application2.show()` and `sys.exit()`. This means the `import registration` step will never finish, because the act of importing it runs `application2.show()`, which blocks until you close the registration window. Then, it will run `sys.exit()`, quitting the program.

I guess what you intended was that the last four lines of the registration module only get executed if you run the script manually, for testing purposes. There is a mechanism built into python that allows exactly that, the `if __name__ == "__main__"` mechanism.

This should fix your code:

Main module:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from start import Ui_Form #py file with start window ui properties 
import registration #registration module
class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.RegButton.clicked.connect(reg_clicked())
        self.openreg=registration.mywindow(self)
        #self.ui.AuthButton.clicked.connect()

    def reg_clicked(self):
        self.openreg.show()
        
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = StartWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Registration module:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import record_proc
from reg import Ui_Reg

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    number_of_samples=1
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Reg()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.RecordButton.clicked.connect(self.Recording)
        self.ui.AuthButton.clicked.connect(self.Register)
        self.ui.CheckLogin.clicked.connect(self.CheckLogin)

def main():
    app2 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application2 = mywindow()
    application2.show()
    sys.exit(app2.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The reasoning behind that is that whenever you run a python file directly with `python3 file.py`, the variable `__name__` gets set to `"__main__"` to signal the file that it now gets executed. So `__name__ == "__main__"` is not a hack, but an official python mechanism.

For more information, read: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: To be precise, `sys.exit()` doesn't quit until the "second" window is closed, as it gets blocked by `app.exec_()`, which starts the Qt event loop (and actually shows the window).

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Reworded to make it clearer.